# Why All .aspx code files will be checked out by changing just one of them?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, checkout

It may look silly to ask this question but tricky for me to know the technical reason behind, so you might share with me the actual reason ;)

Why when using Visual Studio I check out a single file of all files related to an aspx page (.aspx, .aspx.vb, aspx.designer.vb) then in my pending changes I see all the files are checked out!?

for example I just do small change e.g. an attribute in login.aspx then in pending changes will see login.aspx.vb and login.aspx.designer.vb are checked out and **when compare them with previous version NO CHANGE can be found in them?**

Comment: Why is it such an issue to you? (Especially with the edit so you're now **shouting** about it). Those files will frequently get changed for the same reasons and most source control systems will not record an actual change when this changeset is checked in.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, in Visual Studio multiple files can represent a single 'resource' such as a form or a web page. Some of these files are generated automatically by the IDE, and generally contain code which isn't intended to be edited manually.

For example, in a WinForms project, the `form.vb` file will contain all of the methods you're used to seeing, and writing code in, while the `form.Designer.vb` file has IDE generated code that declares and positions the various controls that have been placed on the form in the designer.

These two files represent code for the same resource (a form), but are kept separate to keep inexperienced programmers from making detrimental changes [easily], and to keep your user generated code cleaner. Naturally, though, since they are merely pieces of a whole, editing one affects the other.

For a detailed list of file types in Visual Studio, [have a look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8k0zafxb(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS as your Source Control... Check what settings you have for Source Control... I'm still using 2010 as I still have to develop in XP. In Team --> Team Project Settings --> Source Control you will see some options. In the Check-Out Settings tab I have the Enable Multiple Checkout option checked and Enable Get Latest On Check-Out is unchecked. This has allowed me to checkout single 'resources' at a time. As mentioned above certain files are grouped and editing one will check-out the group.